# What's under the hood of the Entity Framework connection string?

Tags: entity-framework

This a very basic question.

I am learning EF and see the following connection string:

```
<add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/myEF_Northwind.csdl|res://*/myEF_Northwind.ssdl|res://*/myEF_Northwind.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Northwind;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Questions are:

What does **res://*** mean?

Answer (score 0):

**res** means **resource**.  Take a peak at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx) from msdn to get the full skinny on it.

Answer (score 0):

it would also be good to get an understanding on the SSDL, CSDL, and MSL files. They are the responsible to generate the database from model.

It wont improve your coding skills, but it's always good to know :)

Take a look [here](http://dmenin.wordpress.com/2012/07/07/entity-frameworkhow-does-model-first-generate-the-database/)

Comment: Hi Diego, the link cannot be open. Could you check it?